# Python function to download zip file

Tags: python, python-requests, zip

I am trying python function to download zip file `https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.69/win32/chromedriver_win32.zip` 
I tried this and the file is downloaded but damaged not complete

```
import os
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.69/win32/chromedriver_win32.zip'
request = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=headers)

zip_filename = os.path.basename(url)
with open(zip_filename, 'wb') as zfile:
    zfile.write(request.content)
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the content of the created file?

Comment: Did you have a look at `request.status_code`? With the data presented in the question I get a 404.

Comment: Never make an HTTP request and just assume that it works. **Always** check the status code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest ChromeDriver (Win32) can be acquired thus:

```
import requests

zfile = "chromedriver_win32.zip"
url = f"https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/114.0.5735.90/{zfile}"

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    with open(zfile, "wb") as zfile:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(32*1024):
            zfile.write(chunk)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works as for the version you provided but got an error ``Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 10, in <module>
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/122.0.6261.69/chromedriver_win32.zip``  when trying to change the version.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Do you know what HTTP 404 means?

Comment: It means File Not Found. But the original link is found ``https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.69/win32/chromedriver_win32.zip``

Comment: Try entering that URL in your favourite browser then observe the error response

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. The correct url ``https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.69/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip``